# boxplots grouped as factor

Tags: r, boxplot

I'm trying to plot boxplots of multiple variables (columns in a table), grouping the subjects for the levels in cl.med.

This is what I tried:

```
boxplot(scfa[,c("acetate","propionate")]~as.factor(cl.med),outline=FALSE)
```

this is my table:

```
         aceticacid.methylester.1 acetate butyrate fumarate caprate propionate X3phenylpropionate valerate formate
01.BA.V                     4.509  0.1430   0.0168    4e-04  0.0080     0.0174             0.0008   0.0030   5e-04
01.BA.VG                    2.750  0.2736   0.0228    4e-04  0.0047     0.0261             0.0012   0.0014   4e-04
01.BO.VG                   15.281  0.1667   0.0159    6e-04  0.0049     0.0191             0.0008   0.0011   4e-04
01.PR.O                     0.317  0.2470   0.0327    4e-04  0.0078     0.0293             0.0006   0.0016   4e-04
01.TO.VG                    0.210  0.1406   0.0186    4e-04  0.0034     0.0161             0.0006   0.0026   6e-04
```

and this is my class vector

```
01.BA.VG 01.BO.VG  01.PR.O 01.TO.VG 02.BA.VG
1     2    3    1    3    2
```

This produces 3 boxes (for the 3 classes as expected), but the two variables are merged. How could I modify it obtaining 3 boxes for each variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code really shouldn't work at all instead of producing 3 boxes. Usually you have to add them one plot at a time using the `add=TRUE` argument:

```
boxplot(scfa[,c("acetate")]~as.factor(cl.med), outline=FALSE, ylim=c(0, 0.3))
boxplot(scfa[,c("propionate")]~as.factor(cl.med), outline=FALSE, add=TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi! I tried your code, but it actually produce 2 groups of 3 boxplots in vertical. There is a way to have them along the x axis?

Answer (score 0):

You either need to 'melt' or 'stack' your data so that the 2 response columns are stacked.  Or split the data yourself.  Here is an example of the second option:

```
tmp <- split(iris[,c('Sepal.Width','Petal.Width')], iris$Species)
tmp2 <- unlist(tmp, recursive=FALSE)
boxplot(tmp2)
```

Comment: I tried    `tmp=split(scfa[NamesFM,c("butanoicacid","butanoicacid.methylester")],as.factor(cl.med))` and `tmp2=unlist(tmp,recursive=FALSE)` but when I plotted I got only one box...

Comment: @FrancescadeFilippis, what is `NamesFM`?  Were there any warnings/errors?  What do `str(tmp)` and `str(tmp2)` show?

Comment: no, there wasn't any warning. NamesFM is only a vector to select some samples, but without is the same. This is what `str` shows: `> str(tmp)
List of 3
 $ 0: num [1:34] 13.282 12.373 10.272 0.948 26.023 ...
 $ 1: num [1:84] 24.11 1.72 15.47 10 5.93 ...
 $ 2: num [1:186] 15.055 45.788 6.791 15.346 0.357 ...`
`> str(tmp2)
 Named num [1:304] 13.282 12.373 10.272 0.948 26.023 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:304] "01" "02" "03" "04" ...`

Comment: @FrancescadeFilippis, is scfa a matrix or a data frame?  My code should work for data frames, but it looks like you may be working with a matrix instead.  One simple solution is to use `as.data.frame(scfa)` if it is a matrix.